# For loop for bowling score array

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a bowling program that will display the scores given in a multi-line text box. I've manage to get the program giving an output, but when it runs it skips asking for new inputs and just gives 5 0s on seperate lines and nothing else. I'm completely lost, any help is very much appreciated

EDIT: Sorry should have changed errors to reflect the programs changes, it looks like this now. It gives 0's instead of using the value I gave it, but it does ask for each input now.

```
For gameNumber As Integer = 1 To 5 Step 1
        lblEnterScore.Text = "Enter Score for game #" & gameNumber

        Dim Testint As Integer  ' define an Integer for testing

        Try
            Testint = CInt(txtScoreInput.Text)     ' try to convert whatever they entered to Int

        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Entry is not an Integer")   ' If you are here then the CInt failed for some reason, send a message
            txtScoreInput.SelectAll()
            txtScoreInput.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        If txtScoreInput.Text.Contains(".") Then
            MsgBox("Bowling Score must be a whole number.")
            txtScoreInput.SelectAll()
            txtScoreInput.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If txtScoreInput.Text > MAXIMUM_SCORE Or txtScoreInput.Text < MINIMUM_SCORE Then
            MsgBox("Bowling Score must be between 1 and 300.")
            txtScoreInput.SelectAll()
            txtScoreInput.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        scoreInput(gameNumber) = CInt(txtScoreInput.Text)
        ' and store it in the array

        ' and increment the gamecounter for the next time through the loop
    Next
    'btnEnterScore.Enabled = False
    ' place the good score into the multi-line textbox
    txtScoreOutputs.Text = gameScore & vbCrLf & txtScoreOutputs.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you just wanting only 5 scores?

Comment: yeah, but I need it to ask the user for each score

Comment: It's because your txtScore is inside the loop you need to move it outside...

Comment: There's also many other issues as well.Can you use an InputBox?

Comment: this made the loop work but it still gives me 0's instead of the value I typed in, and no I have to use a txtbox for the input(stupid I know but prof said not to use it)

Comment: give me a second... you can remove much of this...

Comment: please see my answer I'm sure it will suit you just fine!

Comment: turn on Option Strict. `If txtScoreInput.Text > MAXIMUM_SCORE` is comparing text (like "cat") to numbers (like 5); is "cat" >5 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Construct your logic like this (pseudo):

```
Loop
{
    AskUserForInput()
    ProcessUserInput()
}
```

The loop part will control how many scores the user is prompted to enter. The AskUserForInput() function will prompt the user to type in a new score, and the ProcessUserInput() function will get the value and store it in an array or print it to the screen, etc.

Your current logic is not waiting for any new user input before trying to add to the scores. You are also getting zeros because you're setting the txtScoreOutputs with gameScore, which doesn't look like it's been set to the user's input.

Comment: I fixed the gameScore and it fixed it, thanks alot for the help

Comment: This isn't an answer, his logic is all messed up.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, here's what I would do... Just a suggestion; I also cut out over half of your code and stopped it from throwing exceptions as well... You can put this in a click event or where ever you need it as well. You can modify this as well to take as many as you want from user input as well not just limit them from entering score's. Your user also has the option to get out of that loop when they choose to do so as well, not keeping them inside the loop...

```
Private ScoreLists As New List(Of Integer) 'Hold your inputted values
Private Const MAXIMUM_SCORE As Integer = 300 'Max score
Private Const MINIMUM_SCORE As Integer = 1 'Min score
Private blnStop As Boolean = False

        Try
            For gameNumber As Integer = 1 To 5
                Dim intScore As Integer = 0

                Do Until (intScore >= MINIMUM_SCORE And intScore <= MAXIMUM_SCORE) OrElse blnStop
                    If Not Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Please enter a score for game # " & gameNumber.ToString), intScore) Then
                        If MsgBox("Bowling Score must be a whole number. Stop getting scores?.", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                            blnStop = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Loop

                ScoreLists.Add(intScore)
            Next

            'Display the results...
            For i As Integer = 0 To ScoreLists.Count - 1
                txtScoreOutputs.Text &= ScoreLists.Item(i.ToString)
            Next

            ScoreLists.Clear()

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```